# Running Gulp via NPM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

[This tutorial](https://blog.wearewizards.io/migrating-to-gulp-4-by-example) runs Gulp via NPM like this:

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "gulp": "./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js"
},

// in your terminal, instead of using gulp, use npm run gulp
npm run gulp
```

Would this work equally well:

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "gulp": "npm run gulp"
}
```

IIUC npm will look in the `node_modules/gulp/bin` directory for the gulp binary?

Comment: The point would be, that `gulp` (from `nodes_modules/.bin`) may not be on the user's PATH, if it is not installed globally. So `npm run gulp` would be a clean and portable way to run it. The `scripts` entry is not needed, though.

Comment: Consider just using `npx gulp` without using scripts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "gulp": "gulp"
}
```

npm will look in the `node_modules/.bin` directory, where each installed module creates symlinks to the relevant bin entry points.

But: In this case, you don't even need the entry for `gulp`. You can run all existing commands in `.bin` with `npm run`, without making explicit `scripts`entries.

See https://blog.jayway.com/2014/03/28/running-scripts-with-npm/ for an introduction and details.